# Twitter Status in wordpress and Tiny Url

Tags: wordpress, twitter, tinyurl

I have a wordpress site. I have a twitter button below every post. What I want is that when a user clicks on it, it should update their twitter status to the following:

the_title().urlencode(get_permalink())
[first the title of the post on which the user clicked the twitter button followed by the url of the post]

mow my problem is that the output from urlencode(get_permalink()) is very large and in the twitter status it displays just plain text not the hyperlink as is expected.  Somewhere i read about tiny url. But what should be the code to pass my url to tiny url and get the shortened version of it so that the hyperlink is active in my twitter status.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Off topic on SO? Take a look at wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer. You can't accept the answer right away, but you can shortly thereafter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution. Thanks if you spent time to view this. Thought to post the answer just in case anyone else faces similar situation

```
function get_tiny_url($url) { 
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url='.$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout); $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```